# Unable to cast the resultant of the query into desired object in hibernate

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am not able to cast the query result to Desired Object **UserTransactionInADay**.

Here is my implementation

```
    @Override
            public UserTransactionInADay getTodaysActivity() {
                Date date = new Date();
                String modifiedDate= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
                Session session = getSession();
                session.clear();
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Query qry = session
                .createQuery(
                                "Select u.infoDate, sum(u.totalActiveUsers) as totalActiveUsers, sum(u.plotsVisited) as plotsVisited, sum(u.totalDataSet) as totalDataSet, sum(u.totalAlerts) as totalAlerts, sum(u.totalCropStages) as 

totalCropStages, sum(u.activitiesClosed) as activitiesClosed, sum(u.totalPlotInput) as totalPlotInput, sum(u.totalHarvest) as totalHarvest from UserTransactionInADay u where u.infoDate = ? group by u.infoDate");
            qry.setString(0, modifiedDate);
            List<UserTransactionInADay> userTransactionInADay = qry.list();
            return userTransactionInADay.get(0);
        }
```

Error I thrown like this

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.raghu.model.UserTransactionInADay
    com.raghu.dao.CropinDaoImpl.getTodaysActivity(CropinDaoImpl.java:92)
    com.raghu.service.CropinServiceImpl.getTodaysActivity(CropinServiceImpl.java:68)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to review some of the [Hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html) a bit. You are selecting a bunch of data and trying to cast it to an entity (I assume) collection.

What your query will return is an Object[][].

Assuming your UserTransactionInADay has the appropriate constructor, you'll want to do something like this:

```
"SELECT NEW UserTransactionInADay(u.infoDate, sum(u.totalActiveUsers) 
    AS totalActiveUsers, SUM(u.plotsVisited) AS plotsVisited,
    SUM(u.totalDataSet) AS totalDataSet, SUM(u.totalAlerts) AS totalAlerts,
    SUM(u.totalCropStages) AS totalCropStages, SUM(u.activitiesClosed) AS activitiesClosed,
    SUM(u.totalPlotInput) AS totalPlotInput, SUM(u.totalHarvest) AS totalHarvest) 
FROM UserTransactionInADay u WHERE u.infoDate = ? GROUP BY u.infoDate"
```

This will return UserTransactionInADay objects, again, assuming there is an appropriate constructor for that type.